# how to make numeric keyboard in kivy(Python)?

Tags: python, keyboard, kivy, numeric-keypad

how to make numeric keyboard in kivy like this,[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it looks like the textinput is binded to an action while focusing on it that pops out a [bubble](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.bubble.html). In the bubble I think you can make a [gridlayout](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.gridlayout.html) of [buttons](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.button.html) and bind a action that will change the text in the textinput.

[Downloading](https://kivy.org/#download) the kivy framework you can check the examples of the widgets in the example/widgets/ directory. You just need to Combine several solutions.

Answer (score 0):

set the `input_type='number'` in your TextInput widget. That will show the numeric keyboard only for that widget, for example in your case I think the best way yo make that widget is to create your own like this:

```
    class yourwidgetname(BoxLayout):
        def __init__((self, **kwargs):
            b = BoxLayout(orientation = 'horizontal')
            b1 = Button(text = '+')
            b2 = Button(text = '-')
            val = TextInput()
            val.input_type = 'number'
            b.add_widget(b1)
            b.add_widget(val)
            b.add_widget(b2)
            self.add_widget(b)
            super(yourwidgetname, self).__init__(**kwargs)
```

I wrote it on the way I didn't try it but this is only to show the input_type property and I hope it gives enough light to the subject.